# Finding address by distance value, in Google Maps Api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I want to find a specific address that, is neither user-configurable nor static or known in advance. In other words I want my application to be able to calculate what address is placed in a distance away from a known location.

Is there a way to define the address or lat/lng, of a place which is placed in a specific distance away from a known location(specific address or lat/,lmg point in map already known). I mean by using the Google Maps Api, can i define what's the address of a place that is 5 meters away from a known location?

To make it more clear, would it be possible to get the address that is in the middle of the distance(known) of two known addresses, especially by using walking(mode) roads for example?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Map API and its associated database is not designed for your requirements. You would require to create your own database or find a vendor of one in the country you require. For example the UK Post Office supply [**PAF**](http://www.poweredbypaf.com/end-user/products/paf-raw-data/) OR for [**US**](http://www.zipinfo.com/products/natzip4/natzip4.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any way to achieve what you are trying. All the locations and addresses that Google Maps provides on the map are the ones that are stored in there servers. If the data about a location is present, you always have a way to find them. So you cannot expect to find a location on the map that doesn't have a value stored in their database. While the database and servers concept of the Google Maps is a way complex, you should understand that something not present in the system cannot be provided or shown. In-short it is not possible.

Comment: I understand but to make it more  clear, the location i am looking for, is an address of a city street, what i mean by that, is that it surely is an address stored in google's database. The problem is that as far as i've seen in the api, i can't search an address by criteria such as distance. For example if i know that Address A and Address B,

Comment: have a 400 meters distance between them, i would like to be able to locate Address C that is located in the middle of this distance(A<->B), so if i drive 200 meters from A towards B, and stop, at this point there must be an address ... For example when you use waypoint in google directions api, you can go from A to B and add a specific third address that you would like to include in your path. Well i would like something like that i think but by using different criteria i think.