# Value returned in json message different than the one stored in database

Tags: php, android, google-maps

My applications stores some latitude longitude for users in a database, these are used for querying the Maps Api. The problem is that i don't get the expected results from the api.

The json response from the Api, includes in some part the lat/lng of the user. What i noticed was, that the lat/lng in the json is different than the one which is stored, in my database.
For example:
These to entries in my database:
21.7694003  39.5593724
Are returned in the json message as follows:
21.75072        39.53207

This is a major problem for me, because i am trying to use the google directions api to get the distance between two points and the results i get are wrong.

I used the file_get_contents() method in php, and the url i use is this:

```
$url= 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='.$nlatend.','.$nlonend.'&destination='.$olatend.','.$olonend.'&region=gr&sensor=false&mode=walking';
```

where $nlonend, $nlatend etc. are variables containing lng/lng coordinates.

It could be possible that google rounds these coordinates, standard procedure, and that my problem is caused from something else but i think that's the source of it.
If anyone could help I would be grateful.

Comment: What's the structure of your database table?  You might be losing precision due to data type.

Comment: Well my longitude latitude fields are varchar(50), and i can see the values being stored correctly in the database (i mean the correct value is stored)

Comment: What code do you exactly mean? From where my variables take their values?

Answer (score 0):

5 decimal places in latitude & longitude equates to approximately 10 metre at the equator. As latitude moves towards the poles the longitude value becomes smaller (5.57 metres at 60°).See [**Wiki**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikiProject_Geographical_coordinates#Precision).

This is nearly as accuracy of [**GPS**](http://wiki.xkcd.com/geohashing/GPS_accuracy)  systems.

Google Maps [**Geocoding**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Results) results has a precision of 7 decimal places.(10cms at equator)

If you require the accuracy of 7 decimal places. You will need to post the relevant code as an **EDIT** to your Question.

Comment: I had a bad coding problem which was causing problem to my variables, thnx very much for the, answer..

Comment: Mr Strachan, I would really like to ask you, if you could take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794543/finding-address-by-distance-value-in-google-maps-api/13794762#13794762